# A generic approach to handle the PUT , POST , DELETE, GET request in python , django

Tags: python, django

So currently what i am doing is that i make class for different type of reuests , suppose there is GET request to fetch some records , so my class will inherit a class that handles the GET requests and all the cases for a GET request will be handled there . So is anyone can suggest a generic approach to handle all kind of requests .

Comment: Use Django Rest framework ?

Comment: Are these requests for some endpoints? Give some context as in where are you trying to use it

Comment: for rest web services

Answer (score 0):

there are already [multiple frameworks](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/api/) that will help you with the task in hand, best known are [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [TastyPie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

My suggestion will be to use one of those. But if you want your own classes - my approach will be similar to GenericViews - to use CBV (Class Based Views) to have full structure to handle my requests (but this will be what others are doing).